# TypeScript: inject context variable into props with HOC

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I am trying to inject a variable from context into a component using a decorator in TypeScript. E.g., to be consumed like so:

```
@Themeable
class Button extends React.Component<Props, State> {
  public render() {
    const { theme: { palette: { primary } } } = this.props;
    return (<button style={{ backgroundColor: primary }} />);
  }
}
```

However, I am having a lot of trouble with typing the HOC such that it arbitrarily binds to any component (including stateless functional component)

Here is my main attempt at it:

```
export default function themeWrapper<Props>(
  COMPONENT: React.ComponentClass<Props & WithTheme> | React.SFC<Props & WithTheme>,
) {
  const themeable: React.SFC<Props & WithTheme> = (
    props: Props & WithTheme,
    { theme }: Context,
  ) => (
      <COMPONENT {...props} theme={merge(defaultTheme, theme)} />
    );

  themeable.contextTypes = {
    theme: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
  };

  return themeable;
}
```

I continuously get the following error:

> Type 'StatelessComponent' provides no match for the signature 'new (props?: Props, context?: any): Button'

What is the appropriate way to create a higher order component which injects variables from *context*

Comment: what version of typescript are you using? I put your code into my vscode and I don't have any compilation errors

Comment: I am using v2.4

Comment: I have 2.5.2, could you try to update your version and check it again?